# Subsetting records that contain multiple values in one column

Tags: postgresql

In my postgres table, I have two columns of interest: `id` and `name` - my goal is to only keep records where `id` has more than one value in name.  In other words, would like to keep all records of `id`s that have multiple values and  **where at least one of those values is B**

UPDATE:  I have tried adding `WHERE EXISTS` to the queries below but this does not work

The sample data would look like this:

```
> test
   id name
1   1    A
2   2    A
3   3    A
4   4    A
5   5    A
6   6    A
7   7    A
8   2    B
9   1    B
10  2    B
```

and the output would look like this:

```
> output
   id name
1   1    A
2   2    A
8   2    B
9   1    B
10  2    B
```

How would one write a query to select only these kinds records?

Comment: because id 6 only has a record for A and not more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description you would seem to want:

```
select id, name
from (select t.*, min(name) over (partition by id) as min_name,
             max(name) over (partition by id) as max_name
      from t
     ) t
where min_name < max_name;
```

Comment: thanks, this worked but I have modified my question slightly - is there a way to incorporate 'WHERE EXISTS` in to the query?

Comment: @the_darkside: it's not considered polite to change the question after you have received an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using EXISTS:

```
select id, name
from test t1
where exists (select *
              from test t2
              where t1.id = t2.id
                and t1.name <> t2.name) -- this will select those with multiple names for the id
  and exists (select *
              from test t3
              where t1.id = t3.id 
              and t3.name = 'B') -- this will select those with at least one b for that id
```

Answer (score 0):

Those records where for their id more than one name shines up, right?
This could be formulated in "SQL" as follows:

```
select * from table t1
where id in (
  select id
  from table t2
  group by id
  having count(name) > 1)
```